# Python logging adds duplicate entries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am adding logging to my Python code. Messages are logged to the file correctly, but it's logging duplicate messages, like re-logging already logged entries to the file.

This is my code:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('Sample')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter =logging.Formatter('%(message)s')

handler=logging.FileHandler('./sample.log')

handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler)


def add(x, y):
    return x + y

num_1=10
num_2=5 
add_result=add(num_1,num_2)
logger.debug("Result: %s "%add_result)
```

Output:

1st run :
   Single output

2nd run:
   Three output

3rd run:
   Six output

Comment: maybe it is a "log appender"? have a look into the logging documentation. It wouldnt make much sense if each logging would recreate the file, wouldnt it? especially if the prog runs every 3 minutes or so... and the only output in the logfile would be the lasts runs one...

Comment: I can't reproduce. With this script, every run adds exactly one line to the log. There's got to be something else going on that isn't reflected in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving your script to a file `test_log.py` and then run `python test_log.py` from the terminal to start your script. This way, each run should always append a single log message to `sample.log`, as expected.

I guess you ran your code multiple times in an interactive python shell. The line `logger.addHandler(handler)` then always adds a new logging handler to your `logger` object, so that after running your code two times, you actually have two logging handlers that are both writing into your `sample.log` --> hence the duplicated entries.

Also, try changing your `formatter` to
`formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-15s %(message)s')`.
This will add a timestamp to your log messages (format `year-month-day hour:minutes:seconds,milliseconds`), allowing you to better debug your code.

Comment: Thanks. My code was running in interactive mode. It works